# Hibernate - ManyToMany sub selects even LEFT JOIN FETCH

Tags: hibernate, hql

guys!
I have two classes two properties in relation ManyToMany

```
public class ExhibitorList {

@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="exhibitor_layouts",
    joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="exhibitor_list_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="layout_id"))
private List<Layout> layouts = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

And

```
public class Layout {

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="layouts",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private List<ExhibitorList> exhibitor = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I'm using HPQ to fetch the entities.

```
final String FIND_ALL_JOIN = "SELECT ex from ExhibitorList as ex LEFT join FETCH ex.layouts order by ex.id";

@Query(FIND_ALL_JOIN)
List<ExhibitorList> findAllJoin();
```

The problem is that this query gets subselects for any Exhibitor that has Layout ( at the moment I have 6 Exhibitors which have layouts.

```
Hibernate: select exhibitorl0_.id as id1_6_0_, layout2_.id as id1_8_1_, exhibitorl0_.catalogue_number as catalogu2_6_0_, exhibitorl0_.exhibitor_name as exhibito3_6_0_, exhibitorl0_.exhibitor_price as exhibito4_6_0_, exhibitorl0_.oracle_number as oracle_n5_6_0_, layout2_.created as created2_8_1_, layout2_.name as name3_8_1_, layout2_.status as status4_8_1_, layouts1_.exhibitor_list_id as exhibito1_5_0__, layouts1_.layout_id as layout_i2_5_0__ from exhibitor_list exhibitorl0_ left outer join exhibitor_layouts layouts1_ on exhibitorl0_.id=layouts1_.exhibitor_list_id left outer join layout layout2_ on layouts1_.layout_id=layout2_.id order by exhibitorl0_.id
Hibernate: select exhibitor0_.layout_id as layout_i2_5_0_, exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id as exhibito1_5_0_, exhibitorl1_.id as id1_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.catalogue_number as catalogu2_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_name as exhibito3_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_price as exhibito4_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.oracle_number as oracle_n5_6_1_ from exhibitor_layouts exhibitor0_ inner join exhibitor_list exhibitorl1_ on exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id=exhibitorl1_.id where exhibitor0_.layout_id=?
Hibernate: select exhibitor0_.layout_id as layout_i2_5_0_, exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id as exhibito1_5_0_, exhibitorl1_.id as id1_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.catalogue_number as catalogu2_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_name as exhibito3_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_price as exhibito4_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.oracle_number as oracle_n5_6_1_ from exhibitor_layouts exhibitor0_ inner join exhibitor_list exhibitorl1_ on exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id=exhibitorl1_.id where exhibitor0_.layout_id=?
Hibernate: select exhibitor0_.layout_id as layout_i2_5_0_, exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id as exhibito1_5_0_, exhibitorl1_.id as id1_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.catalogue_number as catalogu2_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_name as exhibito3_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_price as exhibito4_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.oracle_number as oracle_n5_6_1_ from exhibitor_layouts exhibitor0_ inner join exhibitor_list exhibitorl1_ on exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id=exhibitorl1_.id where exhibitor0_.layout_id=?
Hibernate: select exhibitor0_.layout_id as layout_i2_5_0_, exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id as exhibito1_5_0_, exhibitorl1_.id as id1_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.catalogue_number as catalogu2_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_name as exhibito3_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_price as exhibito4_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.oracle_number as oracle_n5_6_1_ from exhibitor_layouts exhibitor0_ inner join exhibitor_list exhibitorl1_ on exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id=exhibitorl1_.id where exhibitor0_.layout_id=?
Hibernate: select exhibitor0_.layout_id as layout_i2_5_0_, exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id as exhibito1_5_0_, exhibitorl1_.id as id1_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.catalogue_number as catalogu2_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_name as exhibito3_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.exhibitor_price as exhibito4_6_1_, exhibitorl1_.oracle_number as oracle_n5_6_1_ from exhibitor_layouts exhibitor0_ inner join exhibitor_list exhibitorl1_ on exhibitor0_.exhibitor_list_id=exhibitorl1_.id where exhibitor0_.layout_id=?
```

If I use plan Spring Data with findAll(); for example, i get N+1 problem.

How to get all Exhibitors with Layouts with one select

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 select ex from ExhibitorList ex order by ex.id
```

You do not need join with layouts. You have manytomany relationship.

Example using Query:

```
Query q = getSession().createQuery("select ex from ExhibitorList ex order by ex.id" ); 

return (List<ExhibitorList>) q.list();
```

Comment: Yes is does return List of Exhibitors. Check update.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all `Exhibitors` that have `Layouts`, in other words that has not null `List` of `Layouts`, you can use `is not null` and `is not empty` in a  `where` condition:

```
final String FIND_ALL_JOIN = "SELECT ex from ExhibitorList as ex where ( ex.layouts is not null &&  ex.layouts is not empty) order by ex.id";
```

Take a look at [**Expressions** HQL Reference](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) for further details.